# Missing 'field' or 'entity' and/or their related API tags

Tags: discussion, tags

How is it there are now no tags for things like 'field' or 'entity' and/or their related APIs? Some of the questions I am trying to post lately are directly related to them, but I can only enter one tag- '8'.

Comment: There is [tag:entities]. [tag:field] (or the plural one) is not used because there is confusion between entity fields and form fields (i.e. _form elements_).

Comment: Huh, weird. Wasn't popping up for me.

Comment: That's strange: If I write _enti_ in the tag field, I get _entities_ as first suggestion.